# Logic behind back button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am workng on a project in which I have to put back button functionality. Unfortunatly I can't seem to work it out. I have created a back button and it works. But if the user wants to edit the previous form and then submit data again, so it edits the query. I have tried it in my project but it adds another record in the database and doesn't update the previous one. I know I am not using any update query here. Now I am stuck how would it works I can't think of a good logic. I have made a simple form for example. It is written below.

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test1');
    if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
        $first_name = $_POST['fname'];
        $second_name = $_POST['lname'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl`(`first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES
               ('$first_name', '$second_name')";
        $run = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
     }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="nextpage.php">
            First_name: <input type="text" name="fname">
            Second_name: <input type="text" name="lname">
            <input type="submit" name="sub" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

nextpage.php

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test1');
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Next Page</h1>
        <p>The query is submitted press ok to forward and back if you want to go back</p>
        <button>OK</button>
        <button onclick="history.go(-1);">Back</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your expert advice in advance.

Comment: I think better way to do that is to use php session to store form data.

Comment: In my eyes, you need an unique identifer of last stored record. You have to pass this value forward and backward to user session.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly..  ..you have a lot of work to do to be able to to 'UPDATE' a record that you have just created.

Dont bother trying to go 'back' to the original form, go forwards to a new 'edit' form, passing the ID from the record that you have just created.

Use the ID to SELECT that record from the DB and pre-populate the 'edit' form. Add a hidden ID field to the form. Then on submission of the 'edit' form, UPDATE the existing record, using the ID.

Comment: thanks but thats just a basic edit query or basic method..The main thing is i dont wanna go to another page,,i want to redirect to the previous one..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are taking the "back" button too literally. you are emulating the browser's back button. Instead, update your link text to "edit the submitted record", and either modify the submit page with the capability of editing it,  (eg. a hidden input field with the index value of the last created item), or redirect to a page dedicated to editing the submitted record. the user will see it as going back, but the functionality will be different.

submitform:

```
<?php
    $edit = false;
    if(isset($_GET['editid']){
      $edit = true;
      //get the record, and display it in the fields below
    }
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test1');
    if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
        $first_name = $_POST['fname'];
        $second_name = $_POST['lname'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl`(`first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES
               ('$first_name', '$second_name')";
        $run = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
     }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="nextpage.php">
            First_name: <input type="text" name="fname" <?=($edit)?"value=\"".$req["fname"]."\":""?>>
            Second_name: <input type="text" name="lname">
            <input type="submit" name="sub" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

nextpage.php

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test1');
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Next Page</h1>
        <p>The query is submitted press ok to forward and back if you want to go back</p>
        <button>OK</button>
        <button onclick="submitform.php?editid=<?=mysqli_last_return_id()?>">Back</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer to my own question..Hope it would help someone..

test.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
     $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test1');

       if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
       $first_name=$_POST['fname'];
          $second_name=$_POST['lname'];
          $sess_username=$_SESSION['user_name'];
          $sql="INSERT INTO `tbl`(`first_name`, `last_name`,`sess_username`)  
          VALUES ('$first_name','$second_name','$sess_username')";
          $run=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 header("location:nextpage.php");
 }

      if(isset($_POST['upd'])){

     $first_name=$_POST['fname'];
         $second_name=$_POST['lname'];
     $id=@$_GET['id'];
     $upd="UPDATE `tbl` SET               
    `first_name`='$first_name',`last_name`='$second_name' WHERE `id`='$id'";    
      $query=mysqli_query($con, $upd);
        header("location:nextpage.php");
    }
     ?>

        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js">      
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("id") > -1) {
      $('.submit').hide();
   $('.update').show();
   }
     });

  </script>
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
 <form method="POST" action="">
 First_name:<input type="text" name="fname">
 Second_name:<input type="text" name="lname">
 <input class="update" type="submit" value="Update" name="upd"    
 style="display:none;">
 <input class="submit" type="submit" name="sub" value="submit">
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>




 nextpage.php


     <?php
    session_start();
   $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test1');
   $sql="SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE  
   `sess_username`='".$_SESSION['user_name']."'";
   $run=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
   while($res=mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
   $id=$res['id'];
   $firstname=$res['first_name'];
   $lastname=$res['last_name'];
    $sess=$res['sess_username'];
   }

  ?>
 <html>
 <body>
 <h1>Next Page</h1>
 <p>The query is submitted press ok to forward and back if you want to go    
 back</p>
 <button >OK</button>
 <form method="POST" action="test.php">

<?php echo "<a href='test.php?id=$id;'>Back</a>"; ?>
 </form>
</body> 
 </html>
```